# Is .isin() faster than .query()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, isin

###### Question:

Hi,

When searching for methods to make a selection of a dataframe (being relatively unexperienced with Pandas), I had the following question:

**What is faster for large datasets - **.isin() or .query()?****

Query is somewhat more intuitive to read, so my preferred approach due to my line of work. However, testing it on a very small example dataset, query seems to be much slower.

Is there anyone who has tested this properly before? If so, what were the outcomes? I searched the web, but could not find another post on this.

See the sample code below, which works for Python 3.8.5.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

###### Code:

```
# Packages
import pandas as pd
import timeit
import numpy as np


# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Faz'],
               'owner': ['Canyon', 'Endurace', 'Bike']},
                index=['Frame', 'Type', 'Kind'])

# Show dataframe
df

# Create filter
selection = ['Canyon']

# Filter dataframe using 'isin' (type 1)
df_filtered = df[df['owner'].isin(selection)] 

%timeit df_filtered = df[df['owner'].isin(selection)]
213 µs ± 14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


# Filter dataframe using 'isin' (type 2)
df[np.isin(df['owner'].values, selection)]

%timeit df_filtered = df[np.isin(df['owner'].values, selection)]
128 µs ± 3.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


# Filter dataframe using 'query'
df_filtered = df.query("owner in @selection")

%timeit df_filtered = df.query("owner in @selection")
1.15 ms ± 9.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: For those who are looking for the fastest way to do the same thing: `df[np.isin(df['owner'].values, selection)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best test in real data, here fast comparison for 3k, 300k,3M rows with this sample data:

```
selection = ['Hedge']

df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
In [139]: %timeit df[df['owner'].isin(selection)]
449 µs ± 58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [140]: %timeit df.query("owner in @selection")
1.57 ms ± 33.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)
In [142]: %timeit df[df['owner'].isin(selection)]
8.25 ms ± 66.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [143]: %timeit df.query("owner in @selection")
13 ms ± 1.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

df = pd.concat([df] * 1000000, ignore_index=True)
In [145]: %timeit df[df['owner'].isin(selection)]
94.5 ms ± 9.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [146]: %timeit df.query("owner in @selection")
112 ms ± 499 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If check [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#performance-of-query):

> DataFrame.query() using numexpr is slightly faster than Python for large frames

**Conclusion** - The best test in real data, because depends of number of rows, number of matched values and also by length of list `selection`.

Comment: Just a note. It also probably depends on the size of `selection`. What if the selection contains 100 or even 1k items? So the faster approach probably will be `selection = set(items); df[df['owner'].apply(lambda x: x in selection)]`

Comment: @AlexanderVolkovsky - Ya, absolutely agree it depends n the size of `selection`, so the best test in real data. Btw, `df['owner'].apply(lambda x: x in selection)` is slowier, because loops

Comment: because of function calls) yes, it's definitively slower on the small selection size. but the search complexity in set is always O(1) so it can neutralize the cost of a function call after a certain sample size

Comment: @AlexanderVolkovsky - hmmm, is possible prove it by timings?

Comment: just to prove. https://pastebin.com/am2zAHJf. On my laptop the second option works slightly faster than `.isin`. But there is a lot of nuances of course.

Comment: @jezrael and @AlexanderVolkovsky, thanks for your observations! Definitely makes sense that `query` is slower initially due to more function calls, but that the disadvantage decreases with larger sample sizes. As I expect to work with relatively large sample sizes, I won't shy away from `query` - however, I will also compare performance with `isin` when performance becomes more important for my code.

Comment: @Hedge92, i believe the fastest version will be `df[np.isin(df['owner'].values, selection)]`. actually pandas has a huge overhead.

Comment: @AlexanderVolkovsky will definitely try that solution later, will get back to you on that!

Answer (score 2):

A perfplot over some generated data:

[image: benchmark1]

Assuming some hypothetical data, as well as a proportionally increasing `selection` size (10% of frame size).

Sample data for n=10:

`df`:

```
       name  owner
0  Constant  JoVMq
1  Constant  jiKNB
2  Constant  WEqhm
3  Constant  pXNqB
4  Constant  SnlbV
5  Constant  Euwsj
6  Constant  QPPbs
7  Constant  Nqofa
8  Constant  qeUKP
9  Constant  ZBFce
```

`Selection`:

```
['ZBFce']
```

Performance reflects the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#performance-of-query). At smaller frames the overhead of `query` is significant over `isin` However, at frames around 200k rows the performance is comparable to `isin` and at frames around 10m rows `query` starts to become more performant.

I agree with [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67835418/15497888) that, this is, as with most pandas runtime problems, *very* data dependent, and the best test would be to test on *real* datasets for a given use case and make a decision based on that.

---

Edit: Included [@AlexanderVolkovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835338/is-isin-faster-than-query/67835750#comment119901786_67835418)'s suggestion to convert `selection` to a set and use `apply` + `in`:

[image: bench 2]

---

Perfplot Code:

```
import string

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

charset = list(string.ascii_letters)

np.random.seed(5)


def gen_data(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'name': 'Constant',
                       'owner': [''.join(np.random.choice(charset, 5))
                                 for _ in range(n)]})
    selection = df['owner'].sample(frac=.1).tolist()
    return df, selection, set(selection)


def test_isin(params):
    df, selection, _ = params
    return df[df['owner'].isin(selection)]


def test_query(params):
    df, selection, _ = params
    return df.query("owner in @selection")


def test_apply_over_set(params):
    df, _, set_selection = params
    return df[df['owner'].apply(lambda x: x in set_selection)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    out = perfplot.bench(
        setup=gen_data,
        kernels=[
            test_isin,
            test_query,
            test_apply_over_set
        ],
        labels=[
            'test_isin',
            'test_query',
            'test_apply_over_set'
        ],
        n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
        equality_check=None
    )
    out.save('perfplot_results.png', transparent=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The visualization is a good way to support your point, thanks for that. Will consider both `query` and `asin`, but keeping in mind that `query` might outperform `asin` after a certain sample size. Also thanks for sharing a link to the documentation.

Comment: @Hedge92, Please, include the comparison with `df[np.isin(df['owner'].values, selection)]`